# \name multiple authors

Tags: author, affiliation

I am trying to add multiple authors but the `\\` doesn't work on `\name`.

I've been given a template to work with `\name` but I have too many authors and the names don't fit properly. I have 9 authors some of them very long names.

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\title{Title here}


\name{AuthorName1,AuthorName2,AuthorName3,AuthorName4,Authorname5,AuthorName6,AuthorName7, AuthorName8, AuthorName9}
\address
{Address 1 \\ 
Address 2 \\
Address 3}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help how to put the authors names in two rows?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: `\name` isn't defined in the `article` class. Are you sure your template is actually using `article`? Perhaps it's another article-like class. We need to know exactly which class because an answer for one class might not work for another.

Comment: It is an article class yes. I've put also the packages that provided.

Comment: Where does `spconf` come from? it is not a standard package

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. I haven't seen this before either..

Comment: Then how are we suppose to help you

Comment: OK so the `spconf` is a style file for Signal Processing Society Conferences..

Comment: `\name` and `\address` should be defined in `spconf.sty` then...

Answer (score 0):

`article` class does not have a `\name` nor `\address`
You could either simply put it all in the `\author` block using linebreaks like this:

```
\author{Author1, Author2 \\ Institution, Address}
```

Or you could use something like the `authblk` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{Title here}

\author[1]{AuthorName1}
\author[2]{AuthorName2}
\author[3]{AuthorName3}

\affil[1]{Institute 1, Address 1} 
\affil[2]{Institute 2, Address 2}
\affil[3]{Institute 3, Address 3}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should I download the package authblk from somewhere? I tried the above code but says that authblk.sty not found.

Comment: It is available in CTAN, but you should have it installed if you have MikTex or TexLive. Which distribution of LaTeX do you have?